# BigQuery Table multiple parition a day

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, database-partitioning

I am trying to load some Avro format data to BigQuery through the api and I need some partitioning. According to the documentation here
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/tables#TimePartitioning
It will create only one partition a day with the ingestion partition that use the _PARTITIONTIME column. Is it possible to create multiple partition a day by using timestamp field?

Another option I can think about was the ranged partition documented here
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/JobConfiguration#RangePartitioning
however, it was marked as experimental. Not sure it is good for production use?

Comment: What is the use case for multiple partitions per day? Unless you have a lot of data, it wouldn't make that much of a difference. You could consider clustering by a timestamp column if you want efficient time range lookups though.

Comment: You are right. The volume of data per day is a consideration. One partition a day would be still large in my case.

Comment: Does clustering help? If not, why?

Comment: I think it should help. Originally I was thinking smaller partition will help manage the data when I have replace one chunk I don't have to pull out full day worth of data. After your comment, I think if I cluster on the key identifier columns, I can quickly identify the chunk and remove then insert. Since insert is perfectly fine. That should be no issue at all.

Comment: I am on the planning phase of the task, so I have no specific data yet. But I think it should fit the requirements.

Comment: @SamTsai Did clustering work for your use case? Would you provide an answer for your solution?